# Prevent Recycleview scroll when notifyDataSetChange()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, android-scroll

when i notify my `recycleview` using `notifyDataSetChange()` its automatically scroll to top.

I am make this adapter for multi pane purpose.

the app is only for tablet.

so can any please give me the solution for this.??

here is my recycleview adapter.

```
public class PickersListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PickersListAdapter.DataObjectHolder>
{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<PickersModel> pickersModelArrayList;
    private ItemsListFragment fragment;

    public PickersListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PickersModel> pickersModelArrayList, ItemsListFragment itemsListFragment)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.pickersModelArrayList = pickersModelArrayList;
        fragment = itemsListFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public PickersListAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.inflate_list_pickers, parent, false);
        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);

        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PickersListAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, final int position)
    {
        holder.myBackground.setSelected(pickersModelArrayList.get(position).isClicked());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(pickersModelArrayList.get(position).isChecked());
        holder.txtItemName.setText(pickersModelArrayList.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.txtitemQuantity.setText(pickersModelArrayList.get(position).getQuantity());
        Log.e("image url...", pickersModelArrayList.get(position).getItemIcon());
        Glide.with(context).load(pickersModelArrayList.get(position).getItemIcon()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_item_icon).into(holder.imageView);

        holder.myBackground.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < pickersModelArrayList.size(); i++)
                {
                    pickersModelArrayList.get(i).setClicked(pickersModelArrayList.get(position).getItemName().equals(pickersModelArrayList.get(i).getItemName()));
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return pickersModelArrayList.size();
    }

    public class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView txtItemName, txtitemQuantity;
        private LinearLayout myBackground;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            myBackground = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myBackground);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxPickersItems);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItemIconPickerItems);
            txtItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemNamePickerItems);
            txtitemQuantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemQuantityPickerItems);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTag()`, `getTag()` and then use different functions to notify.

Try something like this:

```
holder.myBackground.setTag(position);
        holder.myBackground.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (null != v.getTag()) {
                    int position = (int) v.getTag();
                    for (int i = 0; i < pickersModelArrayList.size(); i++) {
                        pickersModelArrayList.get(i).setClicked(pickersModelArrayList.get(position).getItemName().equals(pickersModelArrayList.get(i).getItemName()));
                    }
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: `setTag` ? what for? just implement `OnClickListener` in your `ViewHolder`, thats all

Comment: `setTag()` is required because in list it should have the position of which view you have clicked. So only changes for that position should reflect, not for every item.

Comment: all you need is to implement `OnClickListener` in your `ViewHolder`, no need for `setTag` / `getTag`, see `ViewHolder` documentation for more info

Comment: it is required. So either you put `ViewHolder` in your tag or `position`. Else everytime it will take position of last displayed item of the list

Comment: did you read the `ViewHolder` docs? did you see various `get*Position` methods?

Comment: Ok let's consider there are 100 items in your list, if you are clicking at 40th position and currently last displayed position in you `RecyclerView` is 45th, which position will it take? `ViewHolder` has many functions for getting position, one which I use normally is `getAdapterPosition`. But inside `onClick()` it will take position of last displayed/binded view, and not of the clicked view

Comment: no, `getAdapterPosition` returns `"the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder."`, if you click on 40th item it will return 40, otherwise what would it be good for if it returned 45?

Comment: Ok then discussion closed. Use `getAdapterPosition()` and notify only that part.